# How do I sell uniques that I don't need

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm a casual gamer mostly playing self-found in Standard. From time to time, I find some uniques that I don't need (some latest catch were [Thousand Ribbons](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Thousand_Ribbons) or [Perandus Blazon](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Perandus_Blazon)). I don't want to vendor them, as they only yield me a couple of shards. Linking them to /trade 1 doesn't help, as /trade 1 is generally overwhelmed with massive and better offers.

How could I sell those uniques to other players? Or, better, how do I find players in need of those uniques?

I'm only playing 1-2 hours a day, irregularly.

EDIT: For anyone reading this question later than March 2016, [Premium stash tabs](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1595024) are more convenient than Procurement. Premium stash tabs are paid, using Procurement is still free.

Comment: Hey @svavil, your edit there should go as an edit to an answer, instead of an edit to a question. Or just make your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Procurement](https://github.com/Stickymaddness/Procurement/) and set up a shop. It's never too early to do that.

People buy this sort of uniques by looking for the cheapest online seller on poe.trade. If you appear online on poe.trade (Procurement has a feature to do that automatically for you as long as the program is open), and have one of the lowest prices listed there, they will contact you. Bingo.

You will occasionally sell items for less than their value. It's perfectly normal; forget it, go on, and learn.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it still worth doing if I am online for 1-2 hours a day and, therefore, can be reached for the actual trading for 1-2 hours a day?

Comment: Also, do I need premium stash tabs to set buyouts? Does it help to set buyout prices?

Comment: @svavil Q1: Yes, it is worth it. People shopping for a 'common' unique just buy it on the spot from any online seller, they don't plan their purchase and wait for the seller to be online. Q2: no, it is irrelevant. Procurement lets you set buyout prices for individual items. The only restriction is that you can only add stash tabs to your shop, not individual items. But if that is a problem for you, just set the b/o for the (few) items you don't want to sell to 999 exalts. Q3: yes, set b/o prices for every 'common' item. You can't have the cheapest price if you don't have a price.

Comment: I am in the process of setting up Procurement. Do I have to start a shop thread in the forum when I set up Procurement? What IGN should I include into the shop thread?

Comment: @svavil Maybe you'd better look for help on the poe forums directly for these issue. Anyway, yes, you have to set up a shop thread and point Procurement to it. IGN is the name of one of your characters (not your account name).

Comment: Well, if I have the uniques to sell in Standard, but spend most of the time running my Talisman char, do I include the name of the Standard character or the Talisman one? Or does it matter?

Comment: @svavil It doesn't matter. The PM will get to you anyway. I know, it's a bit confusing that they don't simply use the account name.

Comment: For anyone else reading, I sold two of my uniques in two hours playing with Procurement on, so it's definitely worth it.